# Looking for Suggestion: If i can avoid UNION ALL in my query?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I Have table named `SOURCE_TABLE` where are 3 columns specific for a day, meaning SUN_W, SUN_WA and SUN_WB for sunday and repeats for Monday as MON_W, MON_WA and MON_WB etc. and in total i have 3 x 7 = 21 columns

Is there any better way to rewrite the below query and avoid UNION ALL?

```
      SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT 
      /*+ parallel(scr,10)
          parallel(el,10)  */ scr.rowid  AS "row_id", scr.*
      FROM SOURCE_TABLE scr
      LEFT OUTER JOIN CITY el ON (el.CITY_NAME  = scr.SUN_W)
      WHERE (el.ROWID IS NOT NULL AND scr.SUN_W IS NOT NULL
      AND GREATEST(scr.SUN_WA, scr.SUN_WB ) IS NULL)
      OR (el.ROWID IS NULL AND scr.SUN_W IS NOT NULL)

      UNION ALL

      SELECT 
      /*+ parallel(scr,10)
          parallel(el,10)  */ scr.rowid  AS "row_id", scr.*
      FROM SOURCE_TABLE scr
      LEFT OUTER JOIN CITY el ON (el.CITY_NAME  = scr.MON_W)
      WHERE (el.ROWID IS NOT NULL AND scr.MON_W IS NOT NULL
      AND GREATEST(scr.MON_WA, scr.MON_WB ) IS NULL)
      OR (el.ROWID IS NULL AND scr.MON_W IS NOT NULL)


      UNION ALL

      SELECT 
      /*+ parallel(scr,10)
          parallel(el,10)  */ scr.rowid  AS "row_id", scr.*
      FROM SOURCE_TABLE scr
      LEFT OUTER JOIN CITY el ON (el.CITY_NAME  = scr.TUE_W)
      WHERE (el.ROWID IS NOT NULL AND scr.TUE_W IS NOT NULL
      AND GREATEST(scr.TUE_WA, scr.TUE_WB ) IS NULL)
      OR (el.ROWID IS NULL AND scr.TUE_W IS NOT NULL)

      UNION ALL 

      ...

      )
```

Comment: Query is not valid.  `cns` is not defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated the question it was a TYPO!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggestion or two which might, or might not help. Have a look, test, decide.

This:

```
WHERE (    el.ROWID IS NOT NULL 
       AND scr.SUN_W IS NOT NULL
       AND GREATEST(scr.SUN_WA, scr.SUN_WB ) IS NULL
      )
   OR (el.ROWID IS NULL AND scr.SUN_W IS NOT NULL)
```

looks suspicious to me. Why do you test whether `ROWID IS NULL`? It can not be null, can it? Therefore, it can be shortened to

```
WHERE scr.sun_w is not null 
  AND greatest(scr.sun_wa, scr.sun_wb) is null
```

Furthermore, `GREATEST` will be `NULL` if one (or both) of parameters are `NULL`, so it would then be

```
WHERE scr.sun_w is not null
  AND (   scr.sun_wa is null 
       OR scr.sun_wb is null
      )
```

I can't tell which one of those will perform better. If `greatest` works OK, leave it, although it isn't that obvious what you are looking for.

---

I'm not sure if this is equivalent of your query (can't test, don't have your data), but - see if it makes sense (contains columns up to Tuesday):

```
select *
from source_table scr left outer join city el 
  on el.city_name in (scr.sun_w, scr.mon_w, scr.tue_w)
where 
  (    scr.sun_w is not null
   and greatest(scr.sun_wa, scr.sun_wb) is null
  )
  or
  (    scr.mon_w is not null
   and greatest(scr.mon_wa, scr.mon_wb) is null
  )
  or
  (    scr.tue_w is not null
   and greatest(scr.tue_wa, scr.tue_wb) is null
  );
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot this suggestion helped!